# How to get the release value?

Tags: regex, sed, grep, cut

I've a file with the below name formats:

```
rzp-QAQ_SA2-5.12.0.38-quality.zip
rzp-TEST-5.12.0.38-quality.zip
rzp-ASQ_TFC-5.12.0.38-quality.zip
```

I want the value as: `5.12.0.38-quality.zip` from the above file names.

I'm trying as below, but not getting the correct value though:

```
echo "$fl_name" | sed 's#^[-[:alpha:]_[:digit:]]*##'
```

`fl_name` is the variable containing the file name.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There are answers of grep, cut and bash in this question, so IMHO this could be useful for future visitors if we keep those tags, to get varity of answers/solutions. So adding back tags here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much easier to use `cut` here:

```sh
cut -d- -f3- file

5.12.0.38-quality.zip
5.12.0.38-quality.zip
5.12.0.38-quality.zip
```

If you want `sed` then use:

```sh
sed -E 's/^([^-]*-){2}//' file

5.12.0.38-quality.zip
5.12.0.38-quality.zip
5.12.0.38-quality.zip
```

Answer (score 7):

You are matching too much with all the alpha, digit `-` and `_` in the same character class.

You can match alpha and `-` and optionally `_` and alphanumerics

```
sed -E 's#^[-[:alpha:]]+(_[[:alnum:]]*-)?##' file
```

Or you can shorten the first character class, and match a `-` at the end:

```
sed -E 's#^[-[:alnum:]_]*-##' file
```

Output of both examples

```
5.12.0.38-quality.zip
5.12.0.38-quality.zip
5.12.0.38-quality.zip
```

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `grep` you could try following code. Written and tested with shown samples.

```
grep -oP '(.*?-){2}\K.*'  Input_file
```

***OR*** as an alternative use(with a non-capturing group solution, as per the fourth bird's nice suggestion):

```
grep -oP '(?:[^-]*-){2}\K.*' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** using GNU `grep` here. in `grep` program using `-oP` option which is for matching exact matched values and to enable PCRE flavor respectively in program. Then in main program, using regex `(.*?-){2}` means, using lazy match till `-` 2 times here(to get first 2 matches of `-` here) then using `\K` option which is to make sure that till now matched value is forgotten and only next mentioned regex matched value will be printed, which will print rest of the values here.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- all filenames contain 3 hyphens (`-`)
- the desired result always consists of stripping off the 1st two hyphen-delimited strings
- OP wants to perform this operation on a variable

We can eliminate the overhead of sub-process calls (eg, `grep`, `cut` and `sed`) by using parameter substitution:

```
$ f1_name='rzp-ASQ_TFC-5.12.0.38-quality.zip'

$ new_f1_name="${f1_name#*-}"                     # strip off first hyphen-delimited string
$ echo "${new_f1_name}"
ASQ_TFC-5.12.0.38-quality.zip

$ new_f1_name="${new_f1_name#*-}"                 # strip off next hyphen-delimited string
$ echo "${new_f1_name}"
5.12.0.38-quality.zip
```

On the other hand if OP is feeding a list of file names to a looping construct, and the original file names are not needed, it may be easier to perform a bulk operation on the list of file names before processing by the loop, eg:

```
while read -r new_f1_name
do
    ... process "${new_f1_name)"

done < <( command-that-generates-list-of-file-names | cut -d- -f3-)
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain bash:

```
echo "${fl_name#*-*-}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a reverse of each line, and get the two last elements separated by "-" and then reverse again:

```
cat "$fl_name"| rev  | cut -f1,2 -d'-' | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

A Perl solution capturing digits and characters trailing a '-'

```
cat f_name | perl -lne 'chomp; /.*?-(\d+.*?)\z/g;print $1'
```